# Superficial magnification

Tags: geometric-optics

so i just started learning about geometrical optics and I'm facing some troubles; suppose u have a system as follows:

[image]

the concave mirror, side AD, and side BC all lie along the y axis, and side ab and cd lie along the z-axis
Note: ABCD is a square

now as expected side AD and BC will get laterally magnified and their new lengths($M*L$) seem justified however it turns out even sides ab and cd get magnified. It doesn't make any sense to me:(

why would they be magnified???
my logic here is if we split the square and along the y axis into infinite strips(of negligible width) and form images of each of these strips the length of ab and cd would be the same . right???Only the lengths of these strips would be magnified M times ???

this is what i mean by dividing
into strips
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of your strips would also be magnified.  Assuming the mirror is symmetrical, and the object and image are centered on the axis of symmetry, then rotation of the system will make no difference.

Comment: why is the width being magnified??

Comment: is my logic wrong???/